# How do I change an if statement to accept string instead of integer

Tags: javascript, html

I cant find a way to change this statement to accept a string value instead of a integer. I am building a shopping cart and I need to use the carts total value and multiply it using a decimal (based on the sum of the total value) the pricerange and decimals are below.

If you know how to edit below to accept a string. Or take a look at [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByBrpv?editors=101) if you can find a way to have rateValue use this string >>>    `grandTotal = (((salesTotal-discount12) * (0.13)) + (salesTotal-discount12))`

```
var chartValue; 
var rateValue = rateValue = grandTotal; 

var priceRange = [ 1000, 2500, 5000, 10000, 15000, 50000 ];
var priceValue = [ 0.02301, 0.01224, 0.02040, 0.01992, 0.01980,0.01980];

for(range in priceRange) 
   if (rateValue >= priceRange[range]) 
        chartValue = priceValue[range];
```

Comment: In the *rateValue* statement, it shouldn't matter if any of the values as strings, the mathematic operations will convert them to numbers. Though you might want explicit conversion for peace of mind. Also, the comparison is not strict, so `'1000' == 1000` is true.

Comment: Why do you want it to accept a string vale?

Comment: I really *really* don't get your question. Care to give us a **clear** example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: My grand total in [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByBrpv?editors=101) is a string. If I do rateValue = mystring or w.e it always gives me a NAN or undefined

Comment: This is what I mean, why is it in codepen, just include it here in your question and leave the relevant stuff only.

Comment: Which "grand total" is that? The one called "salesTotal"?

Comment: Ok, I added the codepen because I thought it would be easier to see the problem there. Any ideas why the above does not cannot use a string

Comment: @Robg there are multiple totals, but using any of them ie ( salestTotal , or the taxed total) causes a NAN or undefined

Comment: Can you show us WHERE you're using them and it causes a `NaN` or `undefined`? Your code seems to work, so I'm not quite sure what the issue is.

Comment: Sure [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emOMEz?editors=101)

Comment: you never set chartValue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with this:

```
var emptyCart = true;
var salesTotal = 0;
var discount12=0;
var subtotal=0;
var cellNum = 1;
var chartValue; 

// seting a value 
var rateValue= (((salesTotal-discount12) * (0.13)) + (salesTotal-discount12));
```

so the value of *rateValue* is 0.

You then do:

```
var priceRange = [ 1000, 2500, 5000, 10000, 15000, 50000 ];
var priceValue = [ 0.02301, 0.01224, 0.02040, 0.01992, 0.01980,0.01980];

for(range in priceRange) 
   if (rateValue >= priceRange[range]) 
        chartValue = priceValue[range];

document.getElementById("pleasework").innerHTML= chartValue;
```

Here *rateValue* isn't `>=` any value in *priceRange*, so *chartValue* remains undefined. The value of *chartValue* isn't reassigned anywhere else, so you see *undefined* written to the document.

PS It's bad form to use for..in with an array (unless you have a good reason to), use a normal for loop with counter or *forEach* with pollyfill.

Comment: I actually figured out why , check it out [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azoYLW) I didnt add this to my other statements.

Answer (score 0):

So in your code you have the following:

```
var chartValue; // this is now undefined
```

Then further down you have:

```
// seting a value 
var rateValue= (((salesTotal-discount12) * (0.13)) + (salesTotal-discount12));
// rateValue is now 0
```

Then here you have the following (which will never be true because `rateValue` is `0`):

```
if (rateValue >= priceRange[range]) 
   chartValue = priceValue[range];
```

So in this case`chartValue` will always be `undefined`

Comment: thank you for posting , I just needed to see this from a better point of view. I have it working . I wish a could give 2 checkmarks thanks.